# Why is this numpy operation running so slowly?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numpy-ndarray

I've written this function to operate on a numpy.ndarray. I was under the impression that this should make my code run faster, however when I get to this function in my code,

```
    for i in range(3,len(data)-3):
        data[i] = (data[i-3] + 2*data[i-2] + 3*data[i-1] + 3*data[i] + 3*data[i+1] + 2*data[i + 2] + data[i + 3])//15
```

it more or less stops. Is there something I'm missing to  optimize this?

Here is the program in full

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vt = 100
WIDTH = 50

def analyze(fname):
    raw_data = np.loadtxt(fname)
    smooth_data = raw_data.copy()

    smooth(smooth_data)

    
    pulses = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(smooth_data) - 2:
        if smooth_data[i + 2] - smooth_data[i] > vt:
            pulses.append(i)
            i += 2
            while i < len(smooth_data) - 2 and smooth_data[i + 1] > smooth_data[i]:
                i += 1
    if not pulses:
        return


    
    for i in range(len(pulses)):
        startPos = pulses[i]
        realWidth = WIDTH

        if i < len(pulses) - 1 and pulses[i] + realWidth > pulses[i + 1]:
            realWidth = pulses[i + 1] - startPos
        
        area = int(sum(raw_data[startPos: startPos + realWidth]))
        print(f"Pulse index: {pulses[i]}\nArea: {area}")

    #write .out file

    _,axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
    xs = raw_data
    ys = smooth_data

    axes[0].plot(xs)
    axes[0].set(title=f"{fname}", ylabel="raw")

    axes[1].plot(ys)
    axes[1].set_ylabel('smooth')
    
    plt.savefig(f"{fname[0:-3]}pdf")

def smooth(data):
    for i in range(3,len(data)-3):
        data[i] = (data[i-3] + 2*data[i-2] + 3*data[i-1] + 3*data[i] + 3*data[i+1] + 2*data[i + 2] + data[i + 3])//15

def main():
    for fname in glob.glob('*.dat'):
        analyze(fname)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Unrelated to your performance problems, I think `smooth` should be operating on a *copy* of `data`, rather than modifying `data` in-place - otherwise the smoothing applied to `data[i]` will affect the smoothing calculation for `data[i+1]`, etc.  In other words the smoothing is biased towards one "side" of the array.

Comment: how big is `data`?

Comment: `data` is a .dat file with a list of around 3000 datapoints

Comment: Are you sure your algorithm is correct? Your nested while loop never terminates if the first condition is not true...

Comment: a couple of things, you dont return a value from `smooth()` and even if you did you haven't assigned anywhere for that data to go.

Comment: The question about `data` was asking about the array that you pass to `smooth` (not the file you loaded).  What is its `shape` and `dtype`.  Iterative calculations like this are not fast in `numpy`.  What is fast is whole-array calculations using compiled code.  Python level iteration is relatively slow.  When you talk about 'faster', what are you comparing it to?  Have you done this with other structures?  list?, pandas?